# How to frame a single(select) query without subquery

Tags: sql, informix

I have framed a query to take a SKU number, but that query has subquery as well.

Could anyone please help me to frame a single query.

```
select p.sku_nbr
from table1 p, table2 s
where p.sku_nbr = s.sku_nbr
  and p.typ_cd = 10
  and p.sku_nbr not in (select sku_nbr from table1
                        where typ_cd <> 10)
```

Comment: This is a single query. (With a sub-query...) Why do you want to remove the sub-query?

Comment: while using this query in java code, I'm getting slowness issue  in executing this query. I have a JSP page that will display the records based on the typ_cd( like 10,11,12,13.to .20). If I do not have subquery, records will get displayed within 2 sec. bUt If I have a subquery then it took around 12 sec to complete this.

Comment: Probably no difference, but have you tried NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN? (You should try NOT EXISTS anyway, it's a "null safe" version of NOT IN...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the schema of both tables nor the data distribution we can only guest.

In the query you mentioned you can do one instant optimization.

In your sub-query you will have only the `sku_nbr` that have `typ_cd equals = 10`, hence there is no need for checking if the `typ_cd` in your query is equal to 10. You can have:

```
SELECT  p.sku_nbr
FROM    table1 p, table2 s
WHERE   p.sku_nbr = s.sku_nbr
        AND p.sku_nbr NOT IN (
                SELECT  p2.sku_nbr
                FROM    table1 p2
                WHERE   p2.typ_cd <> 10
        );
```

You could change the `NOT IN` for `ALL` but the result, in performance, should be the same:

```
SELECT  p.sku_nbr
FROM    table1 p, table2 s
WHERE   p.sku_nbr = s.sku_nbr
        AND p.sku_nbr <> ALL (
                SELECT  p2.sku_nbr
                FROM    table1 p2
                WHERE   p2.typ_cd <> 10
        );
```

I believe, but again I don't have the schema or the data distribution that your best option is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  p.sku_nbr
FROM    table1 p, table2 s
WHERE   p.sku_nbr = s.sku_nbr
        AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  p2.sku_nbr
                FROM    table1 p2
                WHERE   p2.typ_cd <> 10
                        AND p2.sku_nbr = p.sku_nbr 
        );
```

You can also try:

```
SELECT  p.sku_nbr
FROM    table1 p
WHERE   EXISTS (
            SELECT s.sku_nbr 
            FROM   table2 s
            WHERE  p.sku_nbr = s.sku_nbr
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  p2.sku_nbr
                FROM    table1 p2
                WHERE   p2.typ_cd <> 10
                        AND p2.sku_nbr = p.sku_nbr 
        );
```

You should try all the variations with the `SET EXPLAIN ON` clause, compare the time and cost you get.

Check the possibility to create indexes if they don't exist, you can rewrite all queries but the existence of indexes should be the "key".

Answer (score 1):

`p.sku_nbr` must be duplicate, because otherwise the sub-query makes no sense at all. Without some more detail on why the sub-query is required, it's impossible to make firm suggestions on what to do with it.

This looks like a performance problem, and what you really need to do is run this query with `SET EXPLAIN ON` to ascertain what path the optimizer is choosing, and whether there is any index optimization that can be done to improve it.